# How do I manage versions of Android Studio across the team?

Tags: android

I'm a bit worried that the answer is "don't use beta software to develop production applications," but I figure I'll give it a shot anyway.

Currently our team is sharing and android project, using Android Studio to develop it. When "Developer A" updates his locally installed version of AS, there's a chance that it will also require an update to the gradle plugin and build tools. He pushes the changes.

"Developer B" pulls changes, and he's no longer able to build through AS since his installed version is too old. He has to upgrade to the latest AS in order to develop new features.

Now it's time to release a new version, and our build server has the wrong version of the build tools in its local installation of the SDK.

This isn't an ideal solution. I *think* the right way to solve this is to wait until AS 1.0 is released and only subscribe to the "releases" channel for updates.

How have you solved this issue?

Comment: Do you guys use a version control system? Git or something else? Do you version control Android Studio, or the Android sdk? Personally, I do version control even my tools. I got in the habit of doing so with Eclipse. In any case, one problem with Android Studio is that it defaults the canary channel when you first install it. You should make sure that everyone is on the stable channel of the preview release. This solution is not perfect, but changing that channel setting in Android Studio at the very least would go a long way.

Comment: make everyone stay on a same AS build till they release a stable version.

Comment: I think you guys should also have a build server for the beta Android code that's not in production (that should be kept up-to-date and run successfully at least once a day). That would ensure that everyone was on the same page (QA people included).

Comment: We use Git, along with a git-flow workflow. I guess a tricky thing is that AS tends to bug you about updating until you do so. We'll have to make a decision as a team to ignore that popup until we make it simultaneously.

Comment: Joe, you mustn't have understood what I said. Once you set the channel version to a "stable release" instead of "Canary release" inside Android Studio, Android Studio only popups the message to update for stable releases (of the Preview version) instead of popping up the message almost every week. Unfortunately, the default setting for which channel to use on Android Studio is the "Canary release". Once you change that default setting, that will solve ~95% of your problems. I'm quite serious about this.

Comment: Sure, I understand. I'm merely suggesting that when an update is ready (regardless of the update channel), AS will notify you every time it is run (by default). So we can either automatically check for updates on the stable channel as you suggest (which is a good suggestion btw), or completely disable automatic update checking in favor of tracking it as a team.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use one standard version of the development tools across your team.

The approach I've seen used many times on other platforms is to keep your source in a version control system and make sure **everyone** is using the same version of build tools, in this case Android Studio.  There's no reason for developers to be using different versions of build tools unless they are working on different versions of the code.  When you want to move to a newer version, you can create a tag, or a copy of your code from your repo that is guaranteed to work with version X of Android Studio.  Then everyone can migrate together to a new version.

Long story short, it's not a good idea (in my opinion) to have multiple developers on the same project using different versions of development tools.  It leads to inconsistency and is more work than it's worth.  When you want to upgrade to the new version, do it as a team and not as individuals.

I also think that using Android Studio for a production app isn't necessarily a bad thing, the build tools it uses are fairly mature, but the IDE itself could use some improvements.